# Ace editor: everything works except being able to type text into the editor

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ace-editor

For the life of me I can't figure what the problem is. Using the latest Ace editor and it shows up just fine, I can even place the cursor where I want, but I just can't type anything into the editor. Configuration is quite vanilla:

```
var html_editor = ace.edit('html_editor');

html_editor.$blockScrolling = Infinity;
html_editor.getSession().setTabSize(2);
html_editor.getSession().setUseSoftTabs(false);
```

As for background; I use it within a WordPress plugin that disables all of the other scripts that WordPress loads by default so the only script running is the Ace editor. Console is empty and there are no warnings. I've tested with the latest Safari for Mac, Chrome for Mac and Firefox for Mac.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: I also have this problem. `setReadOnly` is most certainly false. I'm using the YAML mode.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: With the current set of information, I doubt it is because of readOnly properly.*

Please check the `setReadOnly` function definition [here](https://ace.c9.io/api/editor.html#Editor.setReadOnly) and use `setReadOnly(false)`, for enabling editing/typing.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the exactly same issue. In CSS I unknowingly hid all textareas by:

```
textarea {
    display: none;
}
```

but it hid textarea in an editor too. More specific CSS selector fixed the issue.